# Retrieving parent element by distant related collection's attribute in HQL?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Good morning, everyone. I need some query help. You can assume I understand relatively complex SQL queries, but this newfangled HQL thing is confusing me a little.

I have 5 objects, A to E. I'm going to use lower case letters (a to e) to refer to attributes in these objects that point to an object of the same upper-case type.

In my class structure, A has a reference to B. B has a reference to C. C has a *collection* (one to many) of D. And D has a reference to E.

```
       />D->E
A->B->C->D->E
       \>D->E
        ...
```

On the database, D is a relationship table that stores the foreign keys of both C and E (the collection is mapped by the reverse attribute D.c).

I need a list of all As whose distantly related collection of D contains a D related to a specific E. I made this pseudoquery (something similar would work in MySQL) to illustrate the problem:

```
select A
from D
left join E on D.e = E
left join C on D.c = C
left join B on B.c = C
left join A on A.b = B
where E = myfilter
```

This doesn't work, however, because there is no 'on' in HQL apparently. I tried variants with syntaxes I found in tutorials but hibernate always throws some obscure error or another (can't dereference collection, invalid token, attribute is not mapped - even though it is, etc.) The main problem seems to be the fact that I don't need to filter by the presence of an actual element of the collection (D) but an attribute of one (E).

Does anyone know how to help? If you need clarification leave a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `on` in HQL, because HQL is used to traverse entity associations, and Hibernate already knows how the associations are mapped in the database. So it inserts the `on` clause in the generated SQL for you. You have to think in terms of entities and their associations instead of thinking in terms of tables. So your query should just be

```
select a from A a
inner join a.b b
inner join b.c c
inner join c.listOfDs d
inner join d.e e
where e.someProperty = :someValue
```

since e needs to be not null to satisfy the condition, there is no point in using left joins. inner joins are usually more performant.

Comment: QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: null.b

Comment: Gah. Can't post self solution because of some reputation idiocy. Well, that's pretty much the solution except the direct paths can be shortened using a.b.c and so on. The problem was apparently I need an alias because HQL performs magic when you assign aliases. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the following (not tested)

```
Select a
From A as a
Left outer join A.b as B
Left outer join B.c as C
Left outer join c.DList as D // DList is the name of the property that is a list of D
Left outer join D.e as E
Where e == filter
```

Comment: QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: D.e